# How to catch successful verification of Google recaptcha automatically?

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

I am developing a website of poems, where I am displaying poem in listing.

The Google `reCAPTCHA` is used to validate human, but I am trying to use it differently.

I am listing `10` poems at first for user - then to read next `10` poems I want to validate user as Human - thus asking to validate Google `reCAPTCHA`. When user successfully validate `reCAPTCHA` I will show next `10` poems.

> The purpose of this scenario is I don't want anyone to parse my site
>   info using script.

Now I want to acknowledge when user successfully verifies captcha automatically, so user does not need to click on `Next` or `Show more` button i.e. when `reCAPTCHA` is verified I want to let be known in some a way. (may be in javascript code)

Let me know how I can achieve it.

Comment: I am not getting any idea -- How should be it done. One idea is to call https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify repetitively and when success Json reply found will display next records.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store in a session when a user is validated as human, and show or don't show recaptcha depending on that session.
Assuming you are using PHP and recaptcha lib, here's an example of how you can achieve that.

https://github.com/google/recaptcha

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    // verified!
    // Store session here, or DB or anything you want
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
}
```